# How can I join different property object collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of my issue class

```
var firstList = new List<object> {
    new { id =1, Name = "item-1"},
    new { id =2, Name = "item-2"},
    new { id =3, Name = "item-3"},
    new { id =4, Name = "item-4"}
}
```

And my second list is like this

```
var secondList = new List<Issue> {
    new Issue{ id =1, Date = "01.01.2017"},
    new Issue{ id =2, Date = "01.02.2017"}
}
```

So I want to create a new list like this. (same id objects will be isPlanned=true)

```
var firstList = new List<object> {
    new { id =1, Name = "item-1", isPlanned=true, Date = "01.01.2017"},
    new { id =2, Name = "item-2", isPlanned=true, Date = "01.02.2017"},
    new { id =3, Name = "item-3", isPlanned=false },
    new { id =4, Name = "item-4", isPlanned=false }
}
```

How can I do this linq functions or lambda operations?

Comment: Left join based on id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join for this:

```
var items = new[] {
    new { id =1, Name = "item-1"},
    new { id =2, Name = "item-2"},
    new { id =3, Name = "item-3"},
    new { id =4, Name = "item-4"}
};
var issues = new[] {
    new { id =1, Date = "01.01.2017"},
    new { id =2, Date = "01.02.2017"}
};
var joined = from item in items
             join issue in issues on item.id equals issue.id into gj
             from sub in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { item.id, item.Name, isPlanned=sub?.Date != null, sub?.Date };
foreach (var t in joined) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", t.id, t.Name, t.isPlanned, t.Date);
}
```

The result will have `null`s when dates are missing, i.e.

```
new { id =1, Name = "item-1", isPlanned=true,  Date = "01.01.2017"},
new { id =2, Name = "item-2", isPlanned=true,  Date = "01.02.2017"},
new { id =3, Name = "item-3", isPlanned=false, Date = null },
new { id =4, Name = "item-4", isPlanned=false, Date = null }
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/otsDLe)

Comment: **object reference not set to an instance of an object** error occured for my lis. I think about  `from sub in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: @bookmarker Are you sure that your `select new ...` is not missing question marks in `isPlanned=sub?.Date != null` and `sub?.Date`? I was getting the same error on ideone (see demo) because I forgot question marks.

Comment: c# 6.0 properties are not supported

Comment: @bookmarker Then you would need to write an old-style expression for these properties, e.g. `Date=sub!=null ? sub.Date : null`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a lambda expression, you could do it the following way:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo(){ Id = 1, Name = "item-1"},
    new Foo(){ Id = 2, Name = "item-2"},
    new Foo(){ Id = 3, Name = "item-3"},
    new Foo(){ Id = 4, Name = "item-4"}
};

List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>()
{
    new Bar(){ Id = 1, Date = "01.01.2017"},
    new Bar(){ Id = 2, Date = "01.02.2017"}
};

IEnumerable<dynamic> result = foos.GroupJoin(bars,
    f => f.Id,
    b => b.Id,
    (foo, bar) => new
    {
        Id = foo.Id,
        Name = foo.Name,
        isPlanned = String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar.SingleOrDefault()?.Date),
        Date = bar.SingleOrDefault()?.Date
    });
```

here are the classes

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

---

I noticed also from the comments from another answer that you are not able to use C#6.0, so this section would not work for you

```
isPlanned = String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar.SingleOrDefault()?.Date),
Date = bar.SingleOrDefault()?.Date
```

You can replace that with the following:

```
isPlanned = bar.SingleOrDefault() == null ? false : String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar.SingleOrDefault().Date),
Date = bar.SingleOrDefault() == null ? null : bar.SingleOrDefault().Date
```